# Transfer Learning model with Keras: using other metrics than accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transfer-learning

I'm working on a binary classification model for leaves from the Swedish leaves data and thought Transfer Learning could be practical. I found [this](https://github.com/codebasics/deep-learning-keras-tf-tutorial/blob/master/18_transfer_learning/cnn_transfer_learning.ipynb) tutorial, but in the compile function, I want to use different metrics than accuracy. When I try to get AUC or  FP/FN/TP/TN, ValueError is raised, claiming the shape of true y (None, 1) and the shape of the y_pred (None, 2) are incompatible.

I fail to understand:

1. why would y_pred have this shape?
2. how can the accuracy be calculated, but not the parts of the confusion matrix?!

A solution without a reasoned explanation is also very welcome :)

```
feature_extractor_model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4"
pretrained_model_without_top_layer = hub.KerasLayer(
    feature_extractor_model, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), trainable=False)
classes_num = 2
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  pretrained_model_without_top_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes_num)
])

model.compile(
  optimizer="adam",
  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=[['acc'], [tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(), tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()]])

model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, steps_per_epoch=9, epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes (e.g. cats and dogs) you could either encode it sparsely as zero or one, or one-hot as [0,1] and [1,0].

Your training data is sparsely, so your loss is SparseCCE. Metrics are just losses functionally, so any metric you use would need to accept sparse. In your case, just write a "custom" loss function that accept a sparse y_true, one-hots it, and passes it to the recall/precision/etc metric function.